# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have two view for chat app.
One is ChatListView(tableview) and the other is ChatDetail.

In the ChatListView class,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell") as! ChatListCell

    if let rvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChatDetail") as? ChatDetail{
        rvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
        //here is the error occur "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        rvc.counter = cell.chatUserName?.text!
        rvc.title = cell.chatUserName?.text!
    }
}
```

In the chatListCell,

```
class ChatListCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var chatUserName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastMessage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastDate: UILabel!

}
```

In the ChatDetail, I declared couner like below.

```
class ChatDetail: JSQMessagesViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var counter: String?
}
```

I tried (cell.chatUserName?.text!)! Like Xcode recommended. But it makes same errors there.

Comment: Which explicitly unwrapped optional is causing problem? When dequeuing the `cell` or when accessing the text property?

Comment: As always, **do not** retrieve data from the view (the table view cell), retrieve it from the model (the data source array)

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't recommend to use ! force unwrapping. 
It seems that your cell.chatUserName?.text is nil. 
Debug that your code can enter if statement

use this code

```
if let chatUserName = cell.chatUserName?.text {
    rvc.counter = chatUserName
    rvc.title = chatUserName
}
```

Comment: Welcome Korean! please check that chatUserName is made as instance like UILable() not just declared. I can't write Korean here so sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've assigned the ChatListCell class to the prototype cell in the Storyboard. The other thing is that the cell will have to be rendered before the `chatUserName` variable is available. Make sure you're not trying to access the those variables before the cell/table renders. One other thing that sticks out is setting a counter to a String. Why not initialize the counter as an Int with a value of 0: `var counter: Int = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell") as! ChatListCell
```

shouldn't be used in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  This may give you a new cell or it may give you an existing cell ready for reuse, but it won't give you the cell that was selected. You should be able to use `indexPath.row` to go directly to your datasource array in order to retrieve the value you want to pass.  There is no need to access the cell.

If you did, however, want to retrieve the cell at the selected row, you would use

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ChatListCell {
    // Do something with the cell
}
```